# How to get nmake to push through errors ( behaviour of make -k)

Tags: c++, cmake, nmake

I'm using cmake to generate an nmake build system using the "NMake Makefiles" generator.  When I compile, even if I specify "nmake /K", the build stops after the first .cpp file which had an error.  I understand that it should not compile targets who have a failed dependency, but several independent source files should be handleable in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU make's -k option also bails out if it gets too many errors, which may confuse users, maybe that's why `nmake` does not support it.

Try `nmake /I` just like `make -i`

Comment: The docs say that ignores all exit codes. The /K behaviour I'm seeing is that it *always* quits after the first file with errors.  Never tries a second.